# Git over Https, how much is exposed?

Tags: git, github, https, bitbucket

We were having a discussion at my job about git, https and interception.

Lets suppose the company decides to start using a git server hosted on cloud (Bitbucket, Github, etc..) over HTTPS.

If some "hacker" starts to monitor all network packets during a pull/push. How much can be exposed?

Project url on origin?
Branch names?
File names?
Anything else?

I am not sure how many requests are made during a commit or if it goes all in one bulk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since its HTTPS, the hacker should not be able to see any of the individual requests -- just a stream of packets (source and destination), so some vague idea of the total volume.  Of, course, if they can MITM break the HTTPS connection, they can then gain a lot of info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git over HTTPS should have no more risk than any other HTTPS connection.

HTTPS is just HTTP run through an encrypted connection. As such all anybody can see (without breaking the encryption) is that you made an HTTPS connection to a domain. Even this can be mitigated with a VPN or SOCKS proxy.

> [HTTPS](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/HTTPS#/Network_layers) encrypts all message contents, including the HTTP headers and the request/response data. With the exception of the possible CCA cryptographic attack described in the limitations section below, ***an attacker should only be able to discover that a connection is taking place between the two parties and their domain names and IP addresses.***

Things like the URL, query string, cookies, etc... are all encrypted.

And, of course, thousands and thousands of companies use remote Git servers every day over HTTPS. Also banks, auctions, messaging... pretty much everything.

Comment: The quote is a litle bit inaccurate as that is not all that leaks -- an attacker can also see the volume of data transmitted in each direction.  So for git over https, they can readily distinguish between a pull and a push.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Chris could you explain a bit more on how the attacker could distinguish between pull and push?

Comment: @ReddyStark They can guess that if you're sending a lot of data it's a push. If you're receiving a lot of data it's a pull. They can't see what's actually happening.